# Find connected components of big Graph using Boost

Tags: c++, boost, graph, bigdata

I have wrote a code for finding connected component of a very big Graph (80 million edges)
but it doesn't work, When the edges number is close to 40 million it crashed.

```
int main(){
    using namespace boost;
    {
        int node1,node2;
        typedef adjacency_list <vecS, vecS, undirectedS> Graph;
        Graph G;
        std::ifstream infile("pairs.txt");
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(infile,line))
        {
            std::istringstream iss(line);
            iss >> node1 >> node2;
            add_edge(node1, node2, G);}
            cout <<"writing file"<<endl;
            int  j = 0;
            ofstream out;
            out.open("connected_component.txt");
            std::vector<int> component(num_vertices(G));
            int num = connected_components(G, &component[0]);
            std::vector<int>::size_type i;
            for (i = 0; i != component.size(); ++i){
                out << i << "\t "<<component[i] <<endl;}
                out.close();
            }
```

Any idea of how can I do this with boost ? or change my Graph data type ?

Comment: How its crashed? Post backtrace?

Comment: It's still running but my CPU usage is very low and when I print index
of file it stopped on 40 million

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using randomized graph data, I can run 40 million edges in about 37s ([peaking at 4.4GiB of memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZhkz.png) according to Massif).

> **`/tmp$`** `od -Anone -w4 -t u2 -v /dev/urandom | head -n 40000000 > pairs.txt`
>   **`/tmp$`** `time ./test`

```
Reading 40000000 done in 5543ms
Building graph done in 3425ms
Algorithm done in 8957ms
writing file
Writing done in 52ms

real    0m37.339s
user    0m36.078s
sys 0m1.202s
```

### 1. Memory allocations

Note however, that I tweaked it by using a vector for the edge list, so that I can reserve the capacity required:

```
typedef adjacency_list<listS, vecS, undirectedS, no_property, no_property, 
         no_property, vecS> Graph;
```

This

- enhanced load performance by removing reallocations
- reduces heap fragmentation

### 2. Vertex id scaling

An important note, too, is that the storage requirements scale with the number of *vertices*. More specifically, they scale with the *domain of vertices*. E.g. loading a file like this:

```
1 7
2 7
5 6
4 9
```

will have ***vastly*** less memory requirements than

```
1 70000
2 70000
5 60000
4 90000
```

In fact, rerunning the above benchmark, with exactly the same input, but **only** the first line altered from

```
 47662 60203
```

into

```
 476624766 602036020
```

Results in the following output:

```
Reading 40000000 done in 5485ms
tcmalloc: large alloc 14448869376 bytes == 0x7c0f2000 @  0x7f30f60aad9d 0x7f30f60caaa9 0x4023ab 0x4019d4 0x7f30f57d7de5 0x401e6a (nil)
Building graph done in 6754ms
tcmalloc: large alloc 2408144896 bytes == 0x49fe46000 @  0x7f30f60aad9d 0x7f30f60caaa9 0x401ced 0x7f30f57d7de5 0x401e6a (nil)
tcmalloc: large alloc 2408144896 bytes == 0x52ffd0000 @  0x7f30f60aad9d 0x7f30f60cb339 0x402e45 0x401d5e 0x7f30f57d7de5 0x401e6a (nil)
Algorithm done in 31644ms
writing file
Writing done in 75921ms

real    2m20.318s
user    1m30.224s
sys 0m49.821s
```

As you can see google's malloc implementation (from [gperftools](http://code.google.com/p/gperftools/)) even warns about exceptionally large allocations and indeed, it runs much slower. (Oh, and the memory usage becomes such that Massif doesn't make it anymore, but I've seen it hit 23GiB in htop).

#### Full Code

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ea3e7914cebb238)** running on 4000 edges:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/connected_components.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <chrono>

using Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

int main()
{
    using namespace boost;
    typedef adjacency_list<listS, vecS, undirectedS, no_property, no_property, no_property, vecS> Graph;
    Graph G;

    // read edges
    auto start = Clock::now();
    std::ifstream infile("pairs.txt", std::ios::binary);

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > as_read;

    int node1, node2;
    while (infile >> node1 >> node2)
        as_read.emplace_back(node1, node2);

    std::cout << "Reading " << as_read.size() << " done in " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(Clock::now() - start).count() << "ms\n";
    start = Clock::now();

    // build graph
    G.m_edges.reserve(as_read.size());
    for(auto& pair : as_read)
        add_edge(pair.first,pair.second,G);

    std::cout << "Building graph done in " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(Clock::now() - start).count() << "ms\n";
    start = Clock::now();

    // find connected components
    std::vector<int> component(num_vertices(G));
    int num = connected_components(G, &component[0]);

    std::cout << "Algorithm done in " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(Clock::now() - start).count() << "ms\n";
    start = Clock::now();

    // write output
    std::cout <<"writing file"<<std::endl;

    std::ofstream out;
    out.open("connected_component.txt");
    for (size_t i = 0; i != component.size(); ++i) {
        out << i << "\t "<< component[i] << std::endl; 
    }

    out.close();
    std::cout << "Writing done in " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(Clock::now() - start).count() << "ms\n";
}
```

Comment: Added some [memory profiling data](http://i.imgur.com/0RQUqCB.png) for good measure

Comment: Can I use edge_list type and find connected components ?

Comment: All the "connected components" require ["An undirected graph. The graph type must be a model of Vertex List Graph and Incidence Graph"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/VertexListGraph.html). EdgeList per se is out. Although, you can have a graph that models both concepts

Comment: I means [this link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/edge_list.html)
according to your comments I must define two graphs

Comment: I know what you meant. And like I said, `connected_graph` does **not** support EdgeListGraph (by itself). You don't need to create two graphs unless you absolutely require an EdgeListGraph elsewhere. Note that there's also Graph implementations that combine concepts (such as _[`VertexAndEdgeListGraph`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/graph_concepts.html#fig:graph-concepts)_)

Comment: But I don't know how to use it.

Comment: @mohammadp What do you want me to say? You ask, I answer. You haven't even specified a goal so I am not about to start working on a demonstration that might not even be what you need. FWIW I think my answer fits your question really well, so instead of unaccepting this, you might open a new question.

Comment: oh...I am so sorry, I am not familiar with this site and I apologize you for my questions. Your solution is helpful but I think it is better to define a graph with edge list instead of adjacency list because I have problem with memory yet.

Comment: Have you located the culprit? Did you profile? (see the linked profiler output for my tests). You could gain a lot by using custom allocators, 32 bit build or using specialized container model altogether. Without a solid idea of where the problem is (my code runs fine for me) it's rather useless to keep throwing "solutions" at it, IMO.

Comment: Code works for 40 million edges but my graph has 80 million edges. 
However, thank you for your replies.

Comment: Can you give me a rough number of unique nodes? As my post indicates, this is a huge factor in predicting memory requirements

Comment: Anyways, with the input file increased to 80Mio lines, it [completes in 1m42s for me](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7974075/). If you want to avoid the temp vector while reading [it completes in 1m2s for me](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7974095/), that's with the slightly optimized reading phase: [live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3193582ee5ad960).