# How to get the OutEdgeList inside a BGL graph

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I use a graph made with the boost graph library and want to access the OutEdgeList to get/set some internal informations (the reserved size of the vectors used to build the OutEdgeList).

I extensively searched the docs but didn't find a function/member, which returns a reference or pointer to the OutEdgeList.

My question is if there is a way to get the graphs OutEdgeList or if boost 'protects' the user from not messing directly with its internals.

[image]

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972344/find-connected-components-of-big-graph-using-boost) I found an example where you could access the EdgeList directly with `graph.m_edges` and also use it as a vector to do  `graph.m_edges.reserve(115960001)` for example, so I hope there should also be a way to access the OutEdgeList too.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: So if understand correctly the 'edges' function that returns a pair of begin-end iterators is not enough for what you want?

Comment: You are right :) Because from my view, having the edge iterator does not let me manipulate the vector which it is iterating over and this is the member I want to manipulate.

Comment: I cannot be sure about it, but the logic is that they are trying to abstract the underlying data structure (it could also be a std::list or a std::set storing the edges), putting a method in the public interface that allows access to the std::vector would be against that.

Comment: But it works also with the EdgeProperties. They are also passed as a template argument and I can get the concrete data structure behind that. There is no conflict in a member being given by a template and returning the member...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to get the OutEdgeList is by iterating over all `m_vertices` and access their `m_out_edges` attribute.

```
VertexIterator vi, vi_end;
for (boost::tie(vi, vi_end) = vertices(graph); vi != vi_end; ++vi){
     graph.m_vertices[*vi].m_out_edges.reserve(6);
}
```

By reserving the proper amount of Edges per Vertex I reduced memory usage from 12GB to 10.5GB.

It took my quite a while to find the members, because I expected them to be in [boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp) but they where in [boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp)

Comment: +1 in principle, but beware that you are using undocumented implementation details, so basically at your own risk. It "took quite a while to find the members" because they are not part of the public interface: you could break invariant unknowingly.

Comment: Undoumented yes, and I am probably short sided when I say this, but reserving just enough space in a vector should have no further side effects. But yes the not documented path is a clear sign of a grayish area in matters of safety...

Comment: I agree with you that `reserve()` is safe, because it has no effects on invariants (performance/allocation efficiency guarantees aren't documented for `adjacency_list`). I thought it was worth pointing out in general. Not everyone knows these things. The answer is nice.